# Limiting characters in textarea - escaped quotes and double quotes take up 2 characters in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, escaping

I want to limit a textarea to a certain number of characters and have written a JavaScript function to notify the user of the remaining number of characters. This limit matches the limit set in MySQL for that particular field.

However, when saving the contents using PHP and mysql_real_escape_string(), it saves quotes and double quotes (and I'd imagine backslashes and all other escaped stuff) with a backslash so that those characters actually take up 2 spaces, thus rendering the JS function inaccurate. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

EDIT: Per deceze's advice I checked if magic quotes were on and they are using a check with get_magic_quotes_gpc().

But I have also checked the directory's .htaccess file and found this flag:

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
```

Which is apparently not turning off magic quotes. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's saving extraneous slashes, it's not actually saving the text you want to save.
It sounds like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled. Disable them.

Comment: As far as I know, magic quotes is not enabled. Forgive me if I'm being obtuse, but won't escaping a string containing quotes using mysql_real_escape_string() add backslashes in front of escaped characters? And then inserting that into MySQL preserves the backslashes? Seems to me it ends up saving 1 character (a quote) as 2.

Comment: @ZDYN Escaping using `mysql_real_escape_string` only escapes characters that would break the query that's inserting the text into the db. The extra slashes are *not* saved in the database. Simplified example: `"These are \"quotes\"."` means the string is `These are "quotes".` The slashes are not part of the string, they're only necessary for valid syntax when writing the string literal. Since you have accepted this answer, I suppose it solved your problem?

Comment: It is the correct answer to that specific problem, but now I have a bigger problem which is figuring out why I can't disable magic quotes. Is there something that can override the local .htaccess file?

Comment: @ZDYN If you can't disable it in php.ini, you can only unescape the values in your app conditionally. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: I don't have write access to the php.ini where I have confirmed it is on. Well that is disappointing. Thank you for your assistance, it was greatly appreciated!